# Is there a better way to write awk with pipes?

Tags: macos, syntax, awk, terminal, zsh

I'm under Mac OsX with a terminal and Zsh. I use this command:

```
awk '/download/ {print $2}' | awk 'NR==1' | awk -F"//" '{print $2}'
```

Is there a better way to write all the awk with only one awk?

Comment: "tube"? You mean the `|`? That's a pipe.

Comment: yes, pipe ! sorry for that (tube is pipe in french..)

Answer (score 2):

This should be what you're after:

```
$ awk '/download/{split($2,a,"//");print a[2];exit}' file
```

Comment: You are welcome. On stackoverflow when your question has been answered you marked as answered by clicking the tick mark next to it. See http://stackoverflow.com/help for the official word.

Comment: `awk '/download/&&NR==1'` is not equivalent to `awk '/download/' | awk 'NR==1'` since the first input line may not contain the string "download". The real equivalent would be something like `awk '/download/&&(!nr++)'`.

Comment: whitespace aids comprehension: `/download/ && NR==1` is way more readable